# How to not display chapter number in section number (titlesec)

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

I'm using `titlesec` to manipulate title and section and other.
Here is what I'm using:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [frame]
    {\normalfont}
    {\filright \footnotesize \enspace LP \thechapter \enspace}
    {6pt}
    {\Large \bfseries \filcenter }

\titleformat{\section}%
  [hang]
  {\Large\bfseries\color{bleu}}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
```

But in my PDF the section are numbered as 1.1 then 1.2 etc...
I would like to suppress the chapter number and only have 1 section 1; 2 section 2 etc...

How can I do that while keeping the rest?

Comment: What about cross-references to the sections? Should they also appear as only `1`, `2`, ...? This may be misleading to the user since you'll have duplicate section numbers across chapters?

Comment: actually, every chapter is completly independant without any cross-references. That's why I don't think it's necessary to keep them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the section numbering would be done on a per-chapter basis with the chapter number included in the representation. In LaTeX terms, this is done using

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
```

In the above construction, `\thesection` is the way the section number is presented, and includes `\thechapter` (the way the chapter number is presented). So to remove the chapter from the section number, add

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: Thank you! It's works exactly as I wanted and now I know how it works :)

Comment: Or, more simply, in your original code for `\titleformat{\section}…`, replace `\thesection` with `\arabic{section}`,  or `\arabic{section}.` if you want a dot after the section number.

Comment: @Bernard: While this might *display* correctly, any `\label`s set for the section will use `\thesection` as the reference which, by default, still includes the chapter number representation `\thechapter`.

Comment: @Werner: I often forget the references problem…